# Constructing a graph with radius two.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, geometric-construction, planar-graphs

From cycles $C_n$, $n\geq6$, I was trying to form a new graph by adding a single vertex to $C_n$ so that the added vertex has eccentricity two and rest have three. I tried for $C_6$ and $C_7$ as given. But unable to do the same for $C_8$. Kindly suggest me how to proceed. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks a lot for the help.

[image]

**P.S. In the figures, red vertex has the eccentricity two.**

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did some silly mistakes. Thank you very much

Comment: Further, I think it can not be extended for $C_{10}$ and higher classes of cycles. I mean cannot be done by adding one vertex. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. For $C_9$ it can still be done, but not for larger cycles.

Comment: @LeenDroogendijk Means we need to add two vertices for that. Am I right?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking: do you want both new vertices to have eccentricity $2$ and all old vertices eccentricity $3$ and check if this is possible for all cycles? I have not thought about this.